create discrete colorbar from colormap in python
I want to use a given colormap (let's say viridis) and create plots and colorbars with discrete colors from that colormap.
I used to use mpl.cm.get_cmap("viridis", 7) for 7 different colors, but this function is deprecated and will be removed. The recommendation is to use matplotlib.colormaps[name] or matplotlib.colormaps.get_cmap(obj) instead, but neither of these allow to specify a number of discrete colors.
So far I have only found complicated workarounds online, is anyone aware of a simple, straightforward way as I had originally?
Thank you!
Here is a sample code with simplified data. It took me a while to get the colorbar axis right how I wanted it, so I would prefer to stick with what I already have instead of a different plt.colorbar() solution.
import os.path as op
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 30})
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

PLOT = '/tmp/'


def main():
    data = np.random.random((20,20))
    data[5,:] = np.nan
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8.3,12))
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

    cm = mpl.cm.get_cmap('viridis', 7)
    cm.set_bad('darkgrey', alpha=1)

    plt.pcolormesh(data, cmap=cm, vmin=0,vmax=1)
    ax.axis('off')

    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.2)
    cb = plt.colorbar(cax=cax)

    plt.savefig(op.join(PLOT, 'test.png'), bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



Please use tags to specify the programming language and toolkit that the question is about as Stack Overflow currently relies on tags for search and notifications. Just added python and matplotlib tags.

ok, thanks! will do that in the future

A simple option to replace matplotlib.cm.get_cmap (deprecated in 3.7.0) is to use matplotlib.pyplot.get_cmap (that was preserved in the API for backward compatibility).
Another one woud be to make a resampled colormap (used under the hood) :

resampled(lutsize) [source]
Return a new colormap with lutsize entries.

Note that the lut is a parameter in get_cmap(name=None, lut=None).
    cm = mpl.cm.get_cmap("viridis", 7)   # (-)
    cm = plt.get_cmap("viridis", 7)      # (+)    


